# PHP - Get highest value from json file

Tags: php, json, max

I would like to get the highest value (y) from the following json-file.

```
   [{
     "name": "Time",
     "data": ["20:40", "20:45", "20:50"]
     },
     {
     "name": "Values",
     "data": [{
               "y": 5774,
               "v1": "Test1",
               "v2": "20:40"
              },
              {
               "y": 5555,
               "v1": "Test2",
               "v2": "20:45"
              },
              {
               "y": 5235,
               "v1": "Test3",
               "v2": "20:50"
              }]
            }]
```

Tried it with max()

```
$json_data = file_get_contents('file.json');
$json = json_decode($json_data, true);
$max_value = max($json["data"]);

echo $max["y"];
```

but I'm not getting any result...

Comment: you use wrong variable maybe should be `$max_value['y']` non `$max['y']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following will retrieve the largest y value:

```
<?php
    $json_data = file_get_contents('a.json');
    $json = json_decode($json_data, true);
    $max_value = max($json[1]["data"]);

    echo $max_value['y'];
?>
```

And the following will retrieve the array with the largest y value:

```
<?php
$json_data = file_get_contents('a.json');
$json = json_decode($json_data, true);
$max_value = max($json[1]["data"]);

print_r($max_value);
?>
```

The problem with your script was you were trying to access a non-existent array on line 3 and you weren't echoing out the $max_value array correctly.

**Warning**

The above code only works because OP's JSON when converted to an array has the element he wants to order his array by as the first indexed value.

So like @MatsLindh stated below in the comments, if you had a value with the key of 'x' instead of 'y', no matter where it's located in the JSON provided it's still the lowest key value placing it as the first indexed value in the array when converted from JSON to an array.

You can still have mix-matched values in the JSON provided as long as the element you want to order by has the lowest value key placing it as the first element indexed in the array. For example:

```
   [{
     "name": "Time",
     "data": ["20:40", "20:45", "20:50"]
     },
     {
     "name": "Values",
     "data": [{
               "y": 5774,
               "v1": "Test1",
               "v2": "20:40",
               "Z" : 8000
              },
              {
               "y": 5555,
               "v1": "Test2",
               "v2": "20:45",
               "Abc": 6754
              },
              {
               "y": 5235,
               "v1": "Test3",
               "v2": "20:50",
               "v3": 6594
              }]
            }]
```

If the above JSON were passed through my first function it would return the desired result the OP was looking for, however.

```
   [{
     "name": "Time",
     "data": ["20:40", "20:45", "20:50"]
     },
     {
     "name": "Values",
     "data": [{
               "y": 5774,
               "v1": "Test1",
               "v2": "20:40",
                "a": 897
              },
              {
               "y": 5555,
               "v1": "Test2",
               "v2": "20:45"
              },
              {
               "y": 5235,
               "v1": "Test3",
               "v2": "20:50"
              }]
            }]
```

With this set of JSON, the element with the key "a" messes the count order up since it's placed at the beginning of the array.

**Conclusion**

If you know that the first value of the array generated from the JSON will always be what you want to count by then my code is fine. Otherwise it's better for you to use @MatsLindh's solution.

Comment: Your answer is too good. Just add print_r($max_value['y']); and it will be perfect because he wants value for Y only, not the array.

Comment: @YousafHassan Point taken. Revised answer. However I saw it best to use `echo` instead of `print_r` since `$max_value['y']` always seems to be a string.

Comment: You are right, echo does the job, and yes i have voted up for your answer because its better than all others including mine.

Comment: But this is not correct - the only reason why this works, is because the associative arrays are of the exact same size (and that the value you want to compare is the first value in the associative array). If there suddenly is one extra key in one of the assocative arrays (or the feed returns them in a different sequence - after all, they're just keys pointing to values), such as `"x": 123` in the last element - then that will always be returned, regardless of the value of `y`.

Comment: @MatsLindh Good point. Updated answer to include warning. However I still feel as if my answer was the best for OP since he/she had provided an example JSON set that follows a certain format.

Comment: @C.Liddell The issue is about the robustness of the code, as it can break for any number of external changes that shouldn't change anything. Thanks for the update.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're *really* trying to get the max value of a certain column in the array (doing just `max($json[1]['data'])` doesn't make sense by itself, as each element in that array is an associative array itself), you'll have to pick the values you want to find the maximum value of first:

```
$max_value = max(array_column($json[1]["data"], "y"));
```

This will extract each value from the `y` column of each element in the `$json["data"]` array, and return the largest value present (through `max`).

`array_column` was added in PHP 5.5, but you can emulate it through a small helper function if you're on an older version:

```
function array_column($array, $column) {
    $ret = array();
    foreach ($array as $elem) {
        $ret[] = $elem[$column];
    }
    return $ret;
}
```

Comment: $json['data'] not exist because he have array objects in context question

Comment: why adding `[1]` after, maybe before adding `[1][data]`

Comment: @Naumov Added it in the right place in the text, in the wrong place in the code. :-) You're my human compiler!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your json_decoded data isn't all in array form, but includes STD objects as well so another way to find the maximum value in your case is by using following algo.

```
$json_data = file_get_contents('file.json');
$json = json_decode($json_data, true);
$max_value = null;
foreach($json[1]->data as $dt){
    if($dt->y > $max_value)
        $max_value = $dt->y;
}
echo $max_value; // There it will output the highest value!
```

Answer (score 0):

You can look this array in php format by `var_dump` function

```
$json_data = file_get_contents('file.json');
$json = json_decode($json_data, true);
$max_value = max($json["data"]);
var_dump($max_value);
```

and you need don't use max because this last element in array
you need check exist key `name = values` for get values by `foreach` or `array_map` for analise you array in exist key `name = values` for exampel

```
$json_data = file_get_contents('file.json');
$json = json_decode($json_data, true);
foreach($json as $_js) {
   if($_js['name'] != 'Values') {
      continue;
   }
   foreach($_js['data'] as $__js) {
       echo $__js['y']; // or push to temporary variable
   }
}
```